# how to replace multiple lines of specific columns of text file

Tags: python, replace, text-files, multiple-columns

i have multiple files, i want to copy two columns from one file and replace it to another two columns in another file. 
the first file contains:

```
ag-109   3.905E-07  
am-241   1.121E-06  
am-243   7.294E-09  
cs-133   1.210E-05  
eu-151   2.393E-08  
eu-153   4.918E-07  
gd-155   2.039E-08  
mo-95   1.139E-05  
nd-143  9.869E-06
```

.......
........

and the second file is :

```
h-1         10  0 0.06674    293   end  
zr          11  0 0.0423     293   end  
u-234       101 0 7.471e-06  293   end  
u-235       101 0 0.0005265  293   end  
u-236       101 0 0.0001285  293   end  
u-238       101 0 0.02278    293   end  
np-237      101 0 1.018e-05  293   end  
pu-238      101 0 2.262e-06  293   end  
pu-239      101 0 0.000147   293   end  
.........  
.......
.   
.    
u-234       1018 0 7.471e-06 293   end  
u-235       1018 0 0.0005265 293   end  
u-236       1018 0 0.0001285 293   end  
u-238       1018 0 0.02278   293   end  
np-237      1018 0 1.018e-05 293   end  
pu-238      1018 0 2.262e-06 293   end
```

i want to replace the first column of file2 from file1, and the 2nd column of file1 to the 4th column of file2.

file 2 contain more lines that i want to continue reading without changing.

second problem is: 
 file2 has repetitive of column 1 for 18 times. the column "101" to "1018"
each 18 nuclides in the first column has different values in column 4

i have tried, to read file1 line by line and the same for the file2.
then start to replace from specific value '11'
including a condition for column 2 to change every time the nuclides iteration finished ( i have 29 nuclides).

```
with open('100_60.inp','a+') as fapp:
    with open("20_3.2_10_100_18.txt") as copf:
        line = fapp.readline()
       # if not line:
        #    break
        source = re.split(r"\s+", line.strip())

        nuclide = copf.readline()
       # if not nuclide:
         #   break
        comp = re.split(r"\s+", nuclide.strip())

if len(source)==6 and source[1] != '11':
           for i in range(29):
               source[3][i]= nuclide[1][i]
               source[0][i] = nuclide[0][i]
               fapp.append(replace(source[0][i],nuclide[0][i]))
if len(source)==6 and source[1] !='101':
               for i in range(29):
               source[3][i]= nuclide[1][i]
               source[0][i] = nuclide[0][i]
               fapp.append(replace(source[0][i],nuclide[0][i]))
```

the expected result must be like this:

```
h-1         10  0 0.06674    293    end  
zr          11  0 0.0423     293    end  
ag-109      101 0 3.905E-07 293   end  
am-241      101 0 1.121E-06 293   end  
am-243      101 0 7.294E-09 293   end  
cs-133      101 0 1.210E-05   293   end  
eu-151      101 0 2.393E-08 293   end  
eu-153      101 0 4.918E-07 293   end  
gd-155      101 0 2.039E-08  293   end  
....  
....  
....
```

Comment: you should write output to a different file rather than appending to the original

Comment: anyhow, my code is not working. could you please provide me some hints

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you manage to convert the text file into a csv working with column is going to be much easier.

if columns are separated by tabs you can also do it in excel without having to script it up yourself https://support.geekseller.com/knowledgebase/convert-txt-file-csv/

After that you could use the csv module and read the file by getting a dict where you can add or remove keys(columns). I can't script up a full working solution for you right now, but I hope this gives you some hint on how to approach it.

Comment: Thank you, i tried to convert my file to csv, but my code input is really sensitive for any space, when i created that, some space are created in other parts of the code, which make it not running.

Comment: that is a little generic, maybe try to give more details and provide some code etc. You can always try to strip for white spaces and stuff like that.